# About action bar on old and new platform in my case

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget, actionbarsherlock

My project requires to support **Android 2.1** and above , on Android 2.1 , the app should have an **action bar** which looks exactly the same as the native action bar on Android 3.2+ .

I tried to use [ActionbarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library to implement the **action bar**, but on android **2.1** platform, there is no `overflow` section(right-most options field) on the action bar, instead, it use the physical **"menu"** button. On android 2.1, there is also no "**arrow**" on the left-most side of the action bar.

So, it seems I have to manually implement the **action bar** for **Android 2.1**.

**my questions:**

**1.** any suggestions on how to manually implement **Action bar** for **Android 2.1**

**2.** The project also requires, if the app running on android 3.2+ platform, the app should use the native action bar API. Which means my project should have the ability to automatically switch to different implementation on different platform version. (That's on android 2.1, use the manually implemented action bar, while on android 2.3+ use native action bar). How to achieve this??

Comment: Have you checked the sample application about `ActionBar` compatibility? http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html

Comment: Yes, I checked that, but I don't know how to use it? Any tutorials available?

Comment: I think you will have to look at the code and implement it directly in your app.

Comment: Ok, then, how to make my app automatically switch between manually made action bar, and the native one on old & new platform respectively??

Comment: per-api layouts.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308308/building-for-froyo-styling-for-ics/9310779#9310779

Answer (score 1):

ActionBarSherlock version 3 uses the native options menu for the overflow which is exactly what the native ICS action bar would use if a hardware menu key was present. It also has an "up" affordance through the same API as the native action bar, `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`.

[image]

Version 4 which is almost completed (and can be tried [here](http://beta.abs.io)) still also has the "up" affordance through the exact same API but also allows you to force the overflow item to appear on pre-3.0 devices despite the presence of the hardware menu key. Try out the newest sample APK...

Not using a library like ActionBarSherlock or Android-ActionBar or even ActionBarCompat at this stage would be a huge waste of your time. The whole reason they were written was to make it easier for you to write the actual app rather than the so-called boilerplate that surrounds it.

Comment: @ Jake, have you tested on Android 2.1 platform, it seems there is no "up" affordance on 2.1 platform when using sherlock v4, that's why I post this question